# How to make custom fonts don't appear in root after production

Tags: angular

I'm using custom fonts on my website, including font-awesome.

In my styles.css I used:

```
 @font-face {
    font-family: "sf-compact-display-regular";
    src: url("../fonts/SF-Compact-Display-Regular.otf") format("opentype"),
    url("../fonts/SF-Compact-Display-Regular.otf") format("woff");
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "sf-compact-display-medium";
    src: url("../fonts/SF-Compact-Display-Meduim.otf") format("opentype"),
    url("../fonts/SF-Compact-Display-Meduim.otf") format("woff");
}
```

After `ng build --aot --prod -c=production` all my fonts appeared in `dist` folder like this:

[image]

I tried to change `../fonts` to `/assets/fonts/` and no fonts in dist appear, but the url became `http://localhost:3030/assets/fonts/myfont.otf` while it should be `http://localhost:3030/myproject/assets/fonts/myfont.otf`.

I don't want to change base in index.html because I want all paths dynamic so I can deploy anywhere.

I tried also to make `myFontStyles.css` and include it in angular.json but same problem.

How can I read all fonts after production from assets not from dist root.

Answer (score 3):

add `~/assets` before `/fonts`.

The **tilde** will be replaced by the `base-href` during building which is `/myproject/` in your project.

So it works for both development and production. :)

```
 @font-face {
    font-family: "sf-compact-display-regular";
    src: url("~/assets/fonts/SF-Compact-Display-Regular.otf") format("opentype"),
    url("~/assets/fonts/SF-Compact-Display-Regular.otf") format("woff");
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "sf-compact-display-medium";
    src: url("~/assets/fonts/SF-Compact-Display-Meduim.otf") format("opentype"),
    url("~/assets/fonts/SF-Compact-Display-Meduim.otf") format("woff");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to change base in index.html because I want all paths dynamic so I can deploy anywhere.

I think the solution here is to specify your base-href path in the build command.

```
ng build --aot --prod -c=production --base-href /myproject/
```

OR

You can add the font files into your angular.json "assets" array.